# Add/Remove ActiveRecord associations without changing the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `Score` and a model `Adjustment`. A `Score` has many `Adjustments`.

I also have a list of scores with adjustements that I wish to be able to update without affecting the db. I want to be able to do something like this:

```
scores.each do |score|
  score.adjustments << some_new_adjustment
  score.adjustments.delete_all(some_old_adjustments)
end
```

In the end, the `scores` array should change, but no query to the db should have been executed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide shows no method to do that https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference

But you should be able to get the associated elements as an array, remove the one you don't want and then assign the new array. It shouldn't change the database until you save the parent.

```
current = score.ajustments.to_a
new_adjustments = current + new_adjustment - old_adjustment
score.adjustments = new_adjustments
```

Comment: `score.ajustments.to_a.reject{|sa| sa ==  old_adjustment }.push(new_adjustment)` if you want to do it functionally.